# Time problem, my clock is completely wrong

Tags: 12.04, windows-8, clock

I am in Bangkok at the present, and the time here is 9.44PM TUE 18-6-2013
but my clock show as 7.33PM WED 19-6-2013

What's wrong with my clock? I have spent a lot of time trouble shooting with UTC configure, but it seems like not the same problem as I have got.

- I set the timezone as Bangkok.
- I installed Ubuntu alongside Windows 8 (*The clock in Win8 is wrong as well, showing the same time as Ubuntu.

How do I fix it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Really Thank you Meer Borg for my language editing, and sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**WARNING USE WITH CAUTION!**

This troubleshooting need to configure your bios clock time setting. It's always indicate that your motherboard battery is out (whether laptop or desktop).

1. You need to press **F2, F8 or F12** depend on your mobo type. After that you will be greeted with **Bios Setup Utility**. From there, search for system time and date configuration and set it to your desire time and date. Then, try to save the configuration and exit. Restart your system. **For laptop please remove the battery**. **Different make different interface**.

[image]

2.After the restart everything should be ok, if the time/clock still display wrong time then go to step 3.

3.You need to change the bios battery. You can do it yourself or sent it to technical person for change to new battery. It is common problem and usually this fix is working for both windows and Ubuntu.

Thank you. It had save me a lot time, hope it will do the same to you.